# iterating over a list of columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. I want to update the value of column C,D, E based on column A and B.

If column A < B, then C, D, E = A, else B. I tried the below code but I'm getting `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` error

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import sys
import re
data=[[0,1,0,0, 0],
      [1,2,0,0,0],
      [2,0,0,0,0],
      [2,4,0,0,0],
      [1,8,0,0,0],
      [3,2, 0,0,0]]
```

df

```
Out[59]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  2  0  0  0
2  2  0  0  0  0
3  2  4  0  0  0
4  1  8  0  0  0
5  3  2  0  0  0
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C', 'D','E'])

list_1 = ['C', 'D', 'E']
for i in df[list_1]:
    if df['A'] < df['B']:
        df[i] = df['A']
    else:
        df['i'] = df['B']
```

I'm expecting below output:

```
df
Out[59]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  2  1  1  1
2  2  0  0  0  0
3  2  4  2  2  2
4  1  8  1  1  1
5  3  2  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.where` 
Return elements are chosen from A or B depending on condition.

`df.assign`
Assign new columns to a DataFrame.

Returns a new object with all original columns in addition to new ones. Existing columns that are re-assigned will be overwritten.

```py
nums = np.where(df.A < df.B, df.A, df.B)
df = df.assign(C=nums, D=nums, E=nums)
```

Comment: Good first answer @Ayush

Comment: So if there were 20 columns, would you make 20 assignments?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df.loc[:,df.columns != 'B']=df.loc[:,df.columns != 'B'].mask(df['B']>df['A'],df['A'],axis=0)
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  2  1  1  1
2  2  0  0  0  0
3  2  4  2  2  2
4  1  8  1  1  1
5  3  2  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve here. Because condition `df['A'] < df['B']` will always return same output in your loop. Just for sake of understanding:

When you do `if df['A'] < df['B']:`

The `if` condition expects a `Boolean`, but `df['A'] < df['B']` gives a `Series` of `Boolean` values. So, it says either use something like

```
if (df['A'] < df['B']).all():
```

OR

```
if (df['A'] < df['B']).any():
```

Answer (score 0):

personally i always use **.apply** to modify columns based on other columns

```
list_1 = ['C', 'D', 'E']
for i in list_1:
    df[i]=df.apply(lambda x: x.a if x.a<x.b else x.b, axis=1)
```

Comment: Is apply efficient on huge datasets?

Comment: @Shanoo my reference is this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is I would only create a DataFrame with columns 'A' and 'B', and then create column 'C' in the following way:

```
df['C'] = df.min(axis=1)
```

Columns 'D' and 'E' seem to be redundant.

If you have to start with all the columns and  need to have all of them as output then you can do the following:

```
df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].min(axis=1)
df['D'] = df['C']
df['E'] = df['C']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `where` in `numpy`:

```
df.loc[:,'C':'E'] = np.where(df['A'] < df['B'], df['A'], df['B']).reshape(-1, 1)
```